# Css images on the right side of the footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a footer with 2 Images who link to a page.

The two links / Images shall stay on the right side of the footer.

The Images shall stand next to each other with a Little margin.

How to I manage this with css?

```
<footer>
    <a href="http://www.google.de/" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a div and float it.

CSS:

```
.images-container {
   float: right;
}

.images-container a {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
<div class="images-container">
    <a href="http://www.google.de/" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the Images fit the footer's height?

Comment: You can try: img { max-width:100%; } or img { max-height: 100%; }. I believe resizing one will resize the other dimension as well. Depending on their original size however they may look strange (stretched etc)

Comment: I dont get it somehow my Images get out of the footer

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle or other demo with the css related to the footer size.

Comment: Thanks, I saw what is happening. The inner container for the images does not have a height so it can be set like this: .images-container{height: inherit;} so it gets the footer height. Then the images can properly benefit from .images-container img {max-height: 100%;} (or height: 100% if you want them to fill). Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gskzo4hm/ (I hope link opens correctly).

Answer (score 0):

hi if you are using bootstrap framework try this code

html

```
<footer class="clearfix">
  <ul class="links pull-right">
   <li> <a href="http://www.google.de/" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
     </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

css

```
.links
{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}
.links li
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float:right for your hyperlinks

```css
footer a {
float:right;
}
footer a:first-child {
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <a href="http://www.google.de/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="logo.jpg">
    </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Direct floating of the "a" elements will reverse their order compared to the markup.

Comment: Yeah. You would have to swap them in the HTML